# From drupal to web2py: taxonomy/tagging and comments?

Tags: comments, tagging, web2py, web2py-modules

I have some sites that I implemented using Drupal.  However as cool as Drupal is I've never been satisfied with coding in it mostly because it's in PHP and I've wanted to work with python.  I've flirted with Django but I just recently discovered web2py and it's definitely caught my eye.  Seems like it may be a sweet spot between Drupal and Django.  Although django-cms is also on my radar.

So now I'm wondering how to re-implement my sites with web2py.  Specifically suppose I have a site about DVD players.  So in Drupal I'd have a CCK type DVD player, with various attributes.  I guess this would correspond to a web2py model.  How would I implement something like Drupal's taxonomy which is like a tagging system in web2py?  Is there a module/plugin/appliance for that?  Or am I manually creating the model schema to handle tagging?

Secondly, how would you handle something like comments and/or reviews on posts?  Again, is there a pre-built plugin for this or do I have roll my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tagging, I don't think web2py has anything quite like the Drupal Taxonomy module, but there are some options. First, you could create your own [many-to-many](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Many-to-Many) model to assign tags to items. Another simpler option is to use web2py's [`list:reference`](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Many-to-Many,-list%3a<type>,-and-contains) field type to de-normalize the many-to-many relationship (the end of that section in the book includes a tagging example).

For existing tagging solutions, you can also check out web2py's [plugin_wiki](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#plugin_wiki), which includes a [tag widget](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#Current-Widgets). You can get it from the [download page](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/download), or pull the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/cube2py/source/browse) directly. Another option is [Powerpack](http://powerpack.tecnodoc.com.ar/powerpack/default/index), which includes the [Instant Press](http://powerpack.tecnodoc.com.ar/powerpack/plugin_instantpress/index) CMS, which includes tagging and categories functionality.

Also, both plugin_wiki and Powerpack include comment plugins.

Finally, you'll generally get more and quicker responses from knowledgeable web2py users on the [web2py mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&pli=1#!forum/web2py).